# Angular 2 pass event from one component to the next

Tags: angular, inject

Parent component I have a list of clients and I am passing the client ID.

`<a (click)="onClient($event, ID)">edit</a>  View`

```
export class ListComponents
 public myformdata: number;
  onClient(ID: number) {

       console.log('loading ID', JSON.stringify(ID));

       this.myformdata = (ID);
       return this.myformdata;
    }
}`
```

On the child constructor I can bind it. But how do I inject the value everytime it is clicked into the child constructor.  I tryied a life cycle hook

```
ngOnChanges(): void {

}
export class ChldComponents{
    constructor(public _dashlit: ListComponents) {
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure of what you are trying to accomplish. If you just trying to pass in the myformdata to the childComponent you can set it on click in your parent component

*parent.component.ts*

```
onClient(ID: number){
    this.myformdata = ID;
}
```

Then use the input directive to pass that into your child component

*child.component.html*

```
<child-component [myInput]="myformdata"></child-component>
```

Now it will be available in your child component and will change whenever the parent component changes this.myformdata. If you need to run some function whenever the input changes you can use the OnChanges lifecycle hook.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/OnChanges-class.html